# Computing a bracket in $charF = p$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Given $L=\mathfrak{gl}(n, F)$ with $charF = p$, where $p$ is a prime number, I would like to prove that given $x$ and $y$ defined as follows $x= e_{p,1} + \sum_{i=1}^{p-1}e_{i,i+1}$ and $y= \sum_{i=1}^p ie_{i,i}$, it is true that $[x,y] = x$. I found instead that $[x,y] = \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} [e_{p,1}, ie_{i,i}] +  \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} [e_{i,i+1}, ie_{i,i}] =  \sum_{i=1}^{p-1}  i\delta_{1,i}e_{p,i} +   \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} i\delta_{i,i} e_{i,i+1} = e_{p,1} - \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} ie_{i,i+1}$.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Have you tried writing down the first interesting case $n=p=3$ explicitly?

Comment: Yes, and I got $e_{3,1} - e_{1,2} - 2e_{2,3}$. Maybe I'm making the same mistake as in the general case, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong

Comment: For a given $i\in\{1,...,p-1\}$, what would you say is $[e_{i, i+1}, y]$?

Comment: Since $i$ is fixed, I write $y= \sum_{j=1}^{p}je_{j,j}$ and I get $\sum_{j=1}^{p-1} j(\delta_{i+1,j} e_{i,j} - \delta_{j,i}e_{j,i+1})$

Comment: I'd say it's $\sum_{j=1}^p (j \delta_{i+1,j} e_{ij} - j \delta_{j,i} e_{j,i+1})$ which is $(i+1)e_{i,i+1}-i e_{i,i+1} = ...$. You cannot take that $j$ out of the bracket. Try e.g. for fixed $i=1$.

Comment: Right, thank you. If you want, you can make that as an answer, so that I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any given $i \in \{1, ..., p-1\}$, we have

$$[e_{i,i+1}, y] = \sum_{j=1}^p (j \delta_{i+1,j} e_{i,j} -j\delta_{j,i}e_{j,i+1}) = (i+1)e_{i,i+1}-i \cdot e_{i,i+1}= e_{i,i+1}.$$

Note that one cannot take the $j$ out of the bracket there. From this the correct result readily follows.

By the way, the characteristic is not used anywhere and the identity is true in $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb Z)$ if you write $y=\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} i e_{i,i}$.